# Visual Studion does not see Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb namespace

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2007

Working on a piece of code that interacts with a sharepoint app on a separate (SP) server. I'm using VS2010 and have referenced and installed Microsoft.SharePoint dll (2007 version) in my Windows Formd project.

VS is not picking up the SharePoint class Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb and SPSite. The entire line is like this: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb sp_web = new Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("mySPsiteurl").OpenWeb();

The SPWeb and SPSite do turn teal as soon as I add their name space in the refereces, but as soon as I run the app they turn black and throws an error of missing assembly reference.

Any ideas as why is this happenning?

Thanks,
Risho

Comment: How would you added this  Microsoft.SharePoint dll for 2007 ? did you copy that manyually in File System ?

Answer (score 0):

How would you added this  Microsoft.SharePoint dll for 2007 ? did you copy that manyually in File System ?

The Sharepoint 2007 .NET assemblies will not appear in the .NET tab because by default they will include SharePoint 2010 assemblies. 
However if you create a Sharepoint 2007 project in VS2010 (the two 2007 workflow projects we have under the Sharepoint tab) these 2007 assemblies will be added for you and by this the SPWeb and SPSite will also be available to you and vanishes your error.

Hope this helps